# Minimization of Floor and Ceiling Functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

So the problem at hand is:

> Find the minimum value of the following function for $ x> 0 $: $$ \def\lc{\left\lceil}   
> \def\rc{\right\rceil} \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor} x\lc x \rc + \lc \frac{1}{x} \rc + x  + \floor{x}x + \floor{\frac{1}{x}} $$

My approach was to set $$ f(x) = \def\lc{\left\lceil}   
\def\rc{\right\rceil} \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor} x\lc x \rc + \lc \frac{1}{x} \rc + x  + \floor{x}x + \floor{\frac{1}{x}} $$

and then find the minimum using the **derivative**.  I was reading previous Maths SE posts on the derivative of the floor and ceiling functions:

1) [What technique should I apply to find the derivative of a ceiling or floor function e.g d/dx(x*⌈x⌉) and d/dx(x*⌊x⌋)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544164/what-technique-should-i-apply-to-find-the-derivative-of-a-ceiling-or-floor-funct)

2) [Derivative of floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305949/derivative-of-floor-function)

Using these, I was able to find out the derivative of nearly $50\%$ of $ f(x)$ but I am not able to proceed ahead and find the entire derivative. Could someone shed some light on how to approach this problem?

Any other methods would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

- For $x>0$ the derivative (if it exists) is  $f'(x)= \lceil x\rceil  + 1  + \lfloor x \rfloor$, which is positive
- but $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have discontinuities at integers and reciprocals of integers
- you might look at least at values of $f(x)$ when $x \in \left\{\frac13,\frac12,1,2,3\right\}$ and at values in the neighbourhood of these
- I suspect that $f(x)$ does not in fact have a minimum, but instead a greatest lower bound

$f(x)$ may look something like this where it does have a derivative:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> $$f(x) = \def\lc{\left\lceil}   
> \def\rc{\right\rceil} \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor} x\lc x \rc + \lc \frac{1}{x} \rc + x  + \floor{x}x + \floor{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Let $[x]$ denote the nearest integer to $x$. Then (modulo corner cases) $\lfloor x \rfloor = \left[x - \frac12\right]$ and $\lceil x \rceil = \left[x + \frac12\right]$. So we rewrite as $$f(x) = x\left[x + \frac12\right] + \left[\frac1x + \frac12\right] + x + x\left[x - \frac12\right] + \left[\frac1x - \frac12\right]$$

Let $\{z\}$ denote an error term whose absolute value is bounded by $z$. Then $[x] = x \pm \{\frac12\}$. So $$f(x) = x\left(x + \frac12 \pm \left\{\frac12\right\}\right) + \left(\frac1x + \frac12 \pm \left\{\frac12\right\}\right) + x + x\left(x - \frac12 \pm \left\{\frac12\right\}\right) + \left(\frac1x - \frac12 \pm \left\{\frac12\right\}\right) \\
= 2x^2 + x + \frac2x \pm \left\{x+1\right\}$$

We can minimise the part without the error bound: $\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} 2x^2 + x + 2x^{-1} = 4x + 1 - 2x^{-2}$ which has extrema where $4x^3 + x^2 - 2 = 0$ with one real root at $x \approx 0.71851$ and value $f(0.71851) = 4.43702$.

If $x > 1$ then $f(x) \ge x^2 + 1 + x + x(x-1) = 2x^2 + 1$, so certainly the minimum value occurs for $x \le \sqrt{\frac{4.43702 - 1}{2}} \approx 1.311$.

In the range $1 < x < 2$, $f(x) = 2x + 1 + x + x + 0 = 4x + 1 > 5$, so we can reject this range. $f(1) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5$, so the minimum must be less than $1$.

In the range $0 < x < 1$, $f(x) = x + \left\lceil\frac1x\right\rceil + x + 0 + \left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor = 2x + \left\lceil\frac1x\right\rceil + \left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor$ is a bit simpler to work with...

We probably want to switch to $g(y) = f(x^{-1})$; then we're interested in the range $y > 1$ for which $g(y) = \frac2y + \lceil y\rceil + \lfloor y\rfloor = \frac2y + 2y \pm \{1\}$. Without the error term the extrema are at $y^2 = 1$, and since we've already rejected $x=1$ as a minimum we're interested in where the error term is in our favour. $\lceil y\rceil + \lfloor y\rfloor - 2y$ clearly depends only on the fractional part of $y$, and in the range $0 < y < 1$ we see that $\lceil y\rceil + \lfloor y\rfloor - 2y = 1 - 2y$, so the error is in our favour when $y$ is just less than an integer.

$g(2 - \varepsilon) = \frac2{2 - \varepsilon} + \lceil {2 - \varepsilon}\rceil + \lfloor {2 - \varepsilon}\rfloor = (1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2})^{-1} + 3 = 4 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + O(\varepsilon^2)$. However, $g(2) = 5$ because both floor and ceiling give $2$.

If $y > 2$ then $g(y) >= \frac2y + 5$, so we can discard that range.

Hence we conclude that $f(x)$ is minimised as $x \to \frac{1}{2 - \varepsilon}$ and $f(x) \to 4$, but that the limit cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $f(x)=x\left(\lceil{x}\rceil+\lfloor{x}\rfloor+1\right)+\left\lceil{\tfrac{1}{x}}\right\rceil+\left\lfloor{\tfrac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor$ or shortly $f(x)=x\times m(x)+r(x).$ The functions $m$ and $r$ are constant on each of the intervals $(k,k+1)$ and $\left(\tfrac{1}{k+1},\tfrac{1}{k}\right),\;k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Therefore study the cases

- $x=1,$ we have $f(1)=5$
- $x\in\mathbb{N},\; x>1$, then $f(x)=2x^2+x+1$ with minimal value $f(2)=11$
- $x\in(k,k+1),\;k\in\mathbb{N},$ then $f(x)=x(2k+2)+1.$ Here $f$ doesn't reach a minimal value, but the infimum is $k(2k+2)+1.$ The smallest limit value is $5$ (as $k=1$).
- $x=\tfrac{1}{k},\;k\in\mathbb{N},\;k>1,$ compute $f\left(\tfrac{1}{k}\right)=\tfrac{2}{k}+2k=2\left(\tfrac{1}{k}+k\right)$ with minimal value $f\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=5$
- $x\in \left(\tfrac{1}{k+1},\tfrac{1}{k}\right),\;k\in\mathbb{N},$ here $f(x)=2x+2k+1.$ Again, $f$ doesn't reach a minimal value, and infimum is $2\times \tfrac{1}{2}+2\times1+1=4$ as $k=1$ and $x\to\tfrac{1}{2}.$

**Conclusion** the function $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ doesn't have a minimum.